# Excel data model - add records to existing table inside data model

Tags: excel, model, powerpivot, powerquery, m

I have a table inside Excel data model, created by importing a csv file. The M code is this:

```
let
Parameters_Table = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Parameters"]}[Content],
FilePath = Parameters_Table{5}[Value],
Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(FilePath),[Delimiter=",", Columns=7, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(Source,{{"Column1", "claim_id"}, {"Column2", "person_id"}, {"Column3", "date"}, {"Column4", "amount"},
{"Column5", "treatment_days"}, {"Column6", "text_short1"}, {"Column7", "text_short2"}}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"date", type date}, {"amount", type number}, {"treatment_days", Int64.Type}})
in
#"Changed Type"
```

The Excel file is given to a colleague, without the source csv file. Some pivots are inside and he can play with them without any issues. Now, I want to give him an update csv file, having a couple of rows only, which should be added to the existing table inside data model.

I created a new query with the update csv file and then I tried a Table.Combine (append query) with the original table and the update table, but this approach needs the source csv file. I also tried Table.InsertRows into original table, but I'm getting a circular reference.

Is there any way to accomplish this, adding rows to a table without having the source csv file?

Adrian

Answer (score 0):

When refreshing Power Query, it needs to get all sources, I would import the source CSV into Excel as a new table (copying and pasting it in, not just letting  it be a loaded table) and reference that in a new Query (delete the source CSV query since  your colleague won't  have access to it) and append to it the new table or file that your colleague needs to add.

Comment: Unfortunately my table has 10m rows.